# Is Google Calendar V3 still supporting API Key Authentication?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

I've been using Google Calendar API for several years for a project and suddenly I received the following error when requesting the list of holiday events:

```
(es.mexican#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com): "Invalid Credentials".
```

According to the docs, it should be still be possible to authenticate with API Key but when testing it returns the same error. Am I missing something?

[image: google-apis-explorer error]

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I'm having this issue too. Oddly enough, it seems completely random. When running off localhost maybe half the calls to the Calendar API work and the other respond with a 401.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It seems to be a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/160190541) that affected many users in the last days

I recommend you to give it a "star" to increase visibility and hope for prompt fixing.

Comment: I changed the authentication method and now use "service account". In the thread that you posted seems that the issue was resolved but I prefer to stick to "service account". Thanks for the reply.